# Change width by mouse

Tags: reactjs, mouse

React has two horizontal components:
`<Menu>`, `<Content>`.

Menu has an initial width of 200px, Content has an auto width - that is, it fills the entire remaining screen.

How to make the width of the Menu component adjustable by the mouse?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/resizable-drawer-34ife?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: There's no easy way to do that. Best if you use some library for that.